# Update existing documents with nested fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I Have an index that already contains documents. wish to populate a field in these documents with nested value. For example; let's say I have a document that looks like this:

```
  {
    "id":"9",
    "title":"Example document",
    "description":"Lorem Ipsum ..."
  }
```

Now, what I wish to do is add a field so that the document would look like this:

```
  {
    "id":"9",
    "title":"Example document",
    "description":"Lorem Ipsum ..."
    "attributes" : [
     {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "color",
         "value": "red"
     },
     {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "size",
          "value": "20"
     }
    ]
  }
```

I've come across [How to write nested schema.xml in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395683/how-to-write-nested-schema-xml-in-solr), and I tried to use this schema and doing atomic update with new values using "add" to the parent field, but I've come across an error.

Here's an XML example of the update process:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">9</field>
        <field name="attributes" update="add">
            <field name="id">1</field>
            <field name="name">color/field>
            <field name="value">red</field>
        </field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

Here's the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:110)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:263)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:190)     
>
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:82)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2637)                                                                                                        
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:794)   
>
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567)      
>
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
>
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)
>
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
>
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
>
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
> ```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like

```
  {
        "id":"9",
        "attributes" :{"add": [
         {
             "id": "1",
             "name": "color",
             "value": "red"
         },
         {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "size",
              "value": "20"
         }
        ]
       }
   }
```